# What happen with all the data after app provider quit

Tags: managed-package, data-loader, appexchange, workbench

I am using 3 apps from a company which recently decided to go out of business. They have given 31 June last day after that they will remove their apps.

I am really worried now as I have no enough time to get someone to create similar apps. My main concern is what will happen to all the data that is stored in managed objects of those apps.

My question is, will my all data go with the removal of apps?! Or it will stay in Database and I can access with Data loader or Workbench?!

Comment: I'd recommend backing up the data by extracting with Workbench or Data Loader as soon as possible to be able to store it externally from the managed package objects in Salesforce.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If the data is stored in the custom objects of managed package, and if you uninstall the package the data will be lost simply.

Although you can take backup of data before un installation.

Comment: You are correct @Mr.Frodo. Every object and data related to that apps are disappeared Today. We managed to get a backup system running and migrate all data there.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "They have given 31 June last day after that they will remove their apps." 
Does that mean that they will remove the apps from appexchange, or will it be removed from your org?

My advice would be that you get a confirmation of what exactly they are planning to do and what that means to you.

I guess they will only remove their apps from the appexchange and you will still be able to benefit from whatever objects are included in the apps you already installed.

Comment: if they are stopping support on `June 31`, it is no wonder they are going out of business :-)

Comment: They will remove apps from appexchange and shut down their business entirely. I talked with them and they are willing to sell all their products at hefty amount to me which I can't afford.  They do not tell me anything about what happen to my data stored in managed objects once they remove apps. Although I have taken all backup now following Mr. Frodo's advise. Can you confirm if I can access the data even after they remove apps?!

@cropredy lol, Its June end actually, my bad!

Comment: I think you can compare it to android apps in the store. If a company removes its apps from the play store, the app on your phone keeps functioning. But feel to let us know if this is not the case.

Comment: @Nielsm Today everything just vanished related to that app from our Salesforce. Its not like Android.